# Git branch on new Computer not tracking master

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I've been working on a feature for the several weeks.  I set up a branch to track the master branch when I stareted

```
git checkout -b my-feature origin/master
```

Then I switched computer and what to continue working on the same feature branch so I created a new local branch on my new computer.

```
git checkout -b my-feature origin/my-feature
```

But not my new local my-feature branch is not picking up changes commited/merged on the origin/master branch.  The remote branch origin/my-feature is still picking up the changes.

What should I do? I was thinking of merging the master branch onto my local feature witch something like

```
git checkout my-feature
git merge --no-ff master
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first checkout is a branch locally called `my-feature`, but called `master` on the remote. Your second checkout is both locally and and the remote called `my-feature`.

You propbably meant to do:

`git branch my-feature # Make a branch
git checkout my-feature # Use it for your local checkout
git push origin my-feature # push it to remote`

Then you can check it out on your second pc with (after git clone):

`git checkout -t origin/my-feature`